# openxlsx in r: openxlsx_getOp and op.openxlsx$ returning different values for same option

Tags: r, openxlsx

Using `openxlsx` package in R. When I run this:

```
> openxlsx_getOp("dateFormat")
```

I get the expected value of `[1] "yyyy-mm-dd"`. However, this code:

```
> op.openxlsx$openxlsx.dateFormat
```

returns `[1] "mm/dd/yyyy"`.

Why are these different?

EDIT:
Sorry. I called `options("openxlsx.dateFormat" = "yyyy-mm-dd")` at the top of my source file. Looks like this is important to specify.

Comment: I cannot replicate this, I get both as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I tried to draft a response, but for being more specific we might need some info on the environment you are working in/locale/if you have personalised anything etc

Answer (score 2):

From `?op.openxlsx`:

> ‘openxlsx_getOp()’ retrieves the ‘"openxlsx"’ options found in
> ‘op.openxlsx’.  If none are set (currently ‘NULL’) retrieves the
> default option from ‘op.openxlsx’.  This will also check that the
> intended option is a standard option (listed in ‘op.openxlsx’) and
> will provide a warning otherwise.

So I suspect it's set to "yyyy-mm-dd" in your environment, hence the discrepancy.
To double check, you can try running `R --vanilla` on your machine (or the equivalent under Windows) and see if it has reverted back to the default `mm/dd/yyyy`